# How to make a regex case-insensitive for a middle part of the expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url, expression

So I am trying to learn regular expressions. I am using a website that provided me with the code for a URL checker, looking like this:

`/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/gm`

The Site also provided some test URLs; the Regex marks the following URLs:

https://www.google.com

http://www.google.com

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

but not:

htt://www.google.com

://www.google.com

which is correct.

However, it does not mark [www.Google.com](http://www.Google.com) because of the capital G.

I am aware I can just use
[A-Za-z0-9] for the 2nd square bracket and it works fine, but I am wondering if there is a way to use the i- and/or ?- operator to do this, meaning only having the middle part of the URL (Google) case insensitive, while everything else remains case sensitive. Thanks!

Comment: Refactor `[a-z0-9]+` into `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-z0-9]*`

Comment: try to learn RegEx on something easier. match standard RFC 3986 is pretty hard even for seniors. anyway look at this one https://rgxdb.com/r/2MQXJD5

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the i flag to make the regular expression case-insensitive. The i flag can be placed at the end of the regular expression, like so:

```
/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/gmi
```

This makes the entire regular expression case-insensitive, which means that it will match both "Google" and "google" in the middle of the URL.
If you want to make only the middle part of the URL (the domain name) case-insensitive, you can use the (?i) inline flag:

This way, only the domain name will be case-insensitive while the rest of the regular expression will remain case-sensitive.

Comment: The `i` flag makes the whole regex case-insensitive, but the `http` part should be case sensitive, so this is not the right answer

Answer (score 0):

In many regex implementations (python, c#, java, perl, ruby, r, swift, go) you can use the `(?i:foo)` pattern to ignore case just for `foo`. This is shown in the commented out `regex0` below.

Unfortunately JavaScript does not supported the "turn case sensitivity within a regex on and off" feature. Therefore you need to use pattern `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead of `[a-z0-9]` if you want to ignore case selectively in a regex.

```js
//const regex0 = /^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?(?i:[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-\.][a-z0-9]+)*)\.[a-z]{2,5}(?::[0-9]{1,63})?(?:\/.*)?$/;
const regex1 = /^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-\.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,63}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/.*)?$/;
const regex2 = /^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\-\.][A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,63}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/.*)?$/;
[
  'https://www.google.com',
  'https://www.Google.com',
  'http://www.google.com',
  'www.google.com',
  'htt://www.google.com',
  '://www.google.com'
].forEach(str => console.log(str, '=> regex1:', regex1.test(str), ', regex2:', regex2.test(str)));
```

Output:

```
https://www.google.com => regex1: true , regex2: true
https://www.Google.com => regex1: false , regex2: true
http://www.google.com => regex1: true , regex2: true
www.google.com => regex1: true , regex2: true
htt://www.google.com => regex1: false , regex2: false
://www.google.com => regex1: false , regex2: false
```

Notes on regex

- simplified the optional `http://`, `https://`, `http://www.`, `https://www.` with nested non-capture groups
- `[\-\.]{1}` and `[\-\.]` are identical, so use the simple version
- TLD max length is 3hars, not 5

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex